# Unable to install php-apc on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, alternative-php-cache

I've got Ubuntu 11.04 running on my Slicehost web server, and I'm trying to install php-apc?

However, when trying to install with

```
apt-get install php-apc
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-apc
```

Any idea how I gan get it installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/php-apc) says is exists, but it's in universe. Have you enabled that repo?